# navicate12 query result chinese disorder

Tags: navicat

`env:
system: macOS 10.12.5
navicat version: 12.0.4`

navicat connect profile:

Transmission Encoding is 65001-[utf-8] Unicode (utf-8)

and my database:

`Database changed
mysql> show variables like 'character_set_database';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)`

is a bug of navicat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set Tranmission Encoding to "Auto"/"Use Database Encoding"

Comment: it was fixed by version 12.0.5, Thanks for help!